Is there a way to suround a text with borders and perhaps define the weight of those borders with Python Docx?
i am working on creating a word file with Docx Python, and at some point I need to surround a specific text or word in a paragraph with borders.
p6 = document.add_paragraph()
p6.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.JUSTIFY
# Add the regular text
p6.add_run("SCOLARITE       Suffisante     ")

# Add the special span
span = p6.add_run("OUI")
span.font.size = Pt(14)
span.font.name = 'Arial'
span.bold = True
span.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)

i want to surround the span by borders.
i have tried going through the Docx library, but I can't seem to find anything related to textborders.
I asked ChatGPT for a solution, and it gave me this code.
# Add borders to the second text element
for i in range(len(p6.runs)):
  if i == 1:
            p6.runs[i].font.underline = True
            p6.runs[i].font.border = True
            p6.runs[i].font.border_size = Pt(2)
            p6.runs[i].font.border_color = (0, 0, 0)  # Set the border color to black

Which will go through each run of the paragraph (p6), and set boundaries for the second run, which in my case is the span. And after checking the docs I found that run.font doesn't have a border property.

"I asked ChatGPT for a solution, and it gave me this code... And after checking the docs I found that run.font doesn't have a border property.": Well, why I am not surprised ;-). AI_is_able_to_program === FALSE.

@AxelRichter Completely agree. Also, len(AI_generated_program_bugs) > float('inf').

Python-docx does not support any text borders up to now. Thus docx.text.run.Font does not provide border nor border_size  nor border_color.  So, as often, the ChatGPT  generated "code" will be useless.
But python-docx is aware that there are bdr elements in Office Open XML for wordprocessing. Therefore, if one knows what XML attributes this bdr element may have, one can set those attributes on low level way to the XML.
Example:
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt, RGBColor
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

document = Document()

paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
paragraph.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.JUSTIFY
# Add the regular text
paragraph.add_run("SCOLARITE       Suffisante     ")

# Add the special text_run
text_run = paragraph.add_run("OUI")
text_run.font.size = Pt(14)
text_run.font.name = 'Arial'
text_run.bold = True
text_run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)

# Add text border to text run
rPr = text_run.element.rPr
rPr_has_bdr = len(rPr.xpath("./w:bdr")) > 0
if rPr_has_bdr:
    bdr = rPr.xpath("./w:bdr")[0]
else:
    bdr = OxmlElement("w:bdr")
    rPr.append(bdr)
bdr.set(qn('w:val'), "single") # line style
bdr.set(qn('w:sz'), "24") # border weight in 8ths pt = 3 pt
bdr.set(qn('w:space'), "4") # space to text in pt = 4 pt
bdr.set(qn('w:color'), "FF0000") # color

document.save("./output.docx")

How can one know about this?
Either read and understand the Office Open XML specifications.
Or, my preferred way: One knows that all Office Open XML files are simply ZIP archives containing XML files and other stuff. So one creates what needed using MIcrosoft Word. Then one saves the file as *.docx. Now one unzips the *.docx (7-Zip can do this directly) and has a look into /word/document.xml to view the XML used.
